# Yii2 Checkboxlist not checked on update

Tags: php, checkbox, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Checkboxlist is not selected during update. here is my code.

```
if(!$model->isNewRecord)
    $list2 = ArrayHelper::map($tax_rule_group_shop->find()->where("id_tax_rules_group =".$model->id_tax_rules_group)->all(),'id_shop','id_shop'); 
 else
    $list2 = array(); 

     $tax_rule_group_shop->id_shop = $list2;
     $listdata=ArrayHelper::map(Shop::find()->all(),'id_shop','name'); ?>
    <?= $form->field($tax_rule_group_shop, 'id_shop[]')->checkboxList($listdata,$list2)->label('Shops');?
```

What is the problem in this code?

If i use Chtml::checkbox it is working but as usual validations are not working.

```
<?= Html::checkboxList('id_shop', $list2, $listdata, ['itemOptions'=>['class' => 'test']]); ?>
```

Comment: maybe this if($model->isNewRecord) should be       if($tax_rule_group_shop->isNewRecord)                                                               or                                                                                                                      <?= $form->field($model, 'id_shop[]')->checkboxList($listdata,$list2)->label('Shops');?>

Comment: No it is $model->isNewRecord. I am working with two models here. I tried your second solution previously but also its not working.

Comment: have u checked this array $list2, it's not empty

Comment: yes i checked it. Its not empty. Html::checkboxList is working fine.

Comment: Okey, also no need send second array is not values. It is tag options. But you send array which is contain values from database.

Answer (score 0):

1. as Nuriddin Rashidov replied !$model->isNewRecord should be !$tax_rule_group_shop->isNewRecord
2. for $list2 use

   ```
   ArrayHelper::getColumn($tax_rule_group_shop->find()
   ->where("id_tax_rules_group =".$model->id_tax_rules_group)->all(),
   'id_shop')
   ```
3. I would rewrite "where" to

   where('id_tax_rules_group=:tid', [':tid'=>$model->id_tax_rules_group])->all()
4. $list2 in

   ```
   $form->field($tax_rule_group_shop, 'id_shop[]')
   ->checkboxList($listdata,$list2)->label('Shops');
   ```

   needs to be in format

   ```
   'options' => [
     'value1' => ['checked' => true],
     'value2'=> ['checked' => true]
   ],
   ```

   Resources: [checkboxList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html#checkboxList()-detail), [activeCheckboxList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#activeCheckboxList()-detail)

Comment: i tried your solution but its still not working. everything is fine. But its not checked during update.